# How to send updated object from Service into Directive Controller function the Angular way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I know I'm missing the AngularJS way to do this correctly.

On `mouseover` in my tagsPanel's view I capture the tag object and first send it into my tagsPanel controller:

**tagsPanel.html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags"
        ng-mouseover="hoverTag(m)"
        ng-mouseleave="leaveTag(m)">
        <div class="tag">{{m.term}}</div>
        <tags-hover ng-model="m"></tags-hover>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**tagsPanel Controller:**

```
vs.hoverTag = function(tagObj) {
    TagDetailsFactory.saveTagDetails(tagObj);
};
```

**tagDetailsFactory**
The last step in my Factory here is what I'm concerned about:

```
tagsHover = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover');
tagsHover.hoveringTag(tag);
```

---

Full Factory code:

```
(function() { "use strict";
    angular.module('tagDetailsFactory', [])
    .factory('TagDetailsFactory', [
        'ApiFactory',
        'ScopeFactory',
        function(ApiFactory,
                 ScopeFactory) {

        // Init ScopeFactory:
        // ------------------
        var tagsHover = {};

        return {
            saveTagDetails : saveTagDetails
        };

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function saveTagDetails(tag) {

            if (tag.percent != undefined) {
                var conditional = tag.percent.toString().charAt(0);
                tag.direction = returnDirection(conditional);
            }

            function floorFigure(figure, decimals) {
                if (!decimals) decimals = 2;
                var d = Math.pow(10, decimals);
                return (parseInt(figure * d)/d).toFixed(decimals);
            };

            ApiFactory.getTagData(tag.term_id).then(function(data) {

                /*
                    Ton of tag updating code here

                    // Algorithm to get percentage change:
                    increase = tag.quantity - tag.previous_quantity;
                    increase = increase / tag.previous_quantity * 100;
                    increase = floorFigure(increase, 2);

                    etc etc...
                 */
                tagsHover = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover');
                tagsHover.hoveringTag(tag);
            });
        };
    }]);
})();
```

^ As you can see above, I crudely grab the scope of the tagsHover directive, then target a function in there and pass on the updated `tag` object.

---

Below is my entire `tagHoverDirective` and *markup*, what would be the ideal **Angular Way** to pass the updated tag object into the `tagHoverDirective` function `hoveringTag`?

```
(function() { "use strict";

    angular.module('tagHoverDirective', [])

    .directive('tagsHover', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl : "tags/tagsHover.html",
            restrict    : "E",
            replace     : true,
            link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
                // console.debug($scope, attrs);
            },
            scope:{
                tag:'=ngModel'
            },
            controller  : ['$scope',
                           'ScopeFactory',
                           'TagDetailsFactory',
                           function($scope,
                                    ScopeFactory,
                                    TagDetailsFactory) {

                // Init tagsHover scope:
                // ---------------------
                var vs = $scope;
                    ScopeFactory.saveScope('tagsHover', vs);

                vs.hoveringTag = function(t) {
                    t.tagsHoverDisplay = true;
                };

                vs.leavingTag = function(t) {
                    t.tagsHoverDisplay = false;
                };
            }]
        }
    });
})();
```

Markup for tagHover.html

```
<div class="tags-hover-container" ng-show="tag.tagsHoverDisplay">
    <div class="tag-info-padding">
        <div class="tweets" ng-hide="!tag.quantity">
            <div class="percentage" ng-hide="tag.length">
                {{tag.tweet_percentage}}%
            </div>
            <div class="tweet-count">{{tag.quantity}} tweets</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tweets-direction" ng-show="!tag.quantity">
            0 tweets
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could inject $rootScope into your factory and broadcast a message with a tagIdentifier and tag object in a data object , under the event name "tag_update" (or something of the like). Then set a scope.on("tag_update") from the directive and check if the identifier matches the one you're interested in. This also gives you the flexibility of listening for tag update events in other locations, if you want some sort of higher level UI change when a tag updates. Let me know if you're interested in this, and I can demo an example

Comment: Another option would be to inject the factory into your directive, and register callbacks in that factory by an identifier (or some condition), and when the tag updates in the factory, to check the identifier/condition and execute the callback (which takes a tag argument, and sets it on the scope from within the directive) with the tag as the param passed in from the factory.

Comment: That 2nd option sounds like the right way to do it, any simple examples you could link to / provide? I will update my question with the full Factory code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked together a basic example of notifying the directive of an update via callback based on what type of tag it's interested in observing. I put in three text fields, the identifier text field is the one that actually matters.

First the markup, which is just an empty directive, whose template will render without the tag data initially, the form will tag in the values that we'll be storing.

```
<sample-directive></sample-directive>


<form ng-submit="addNewTag()">

    <input placeholder="tag type identifier" type="text" ng-model="tag.tagIdentifier">
    <input placeholder="tag name" type="text" ng-model="tag.tagName">
    <input placeholder="tag message" type="text" ng-model="tag.tagMessage">
    <input type="submit" value="Add new tag">

</form>
```

The controller for adding the tag

```
.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope, sampleService) {

$scope.tag = {
    tagName: "",
    tagIdentifier: "",
    tagMessage: ""
}

$scope.addNewTag = function() {
    var tag = {};

    tag.message = $scope.tag.tagMessage;
    tag.name = $scope.tag.tagName;

    sampleService.setTag(tag, $scope.tag.tagIdentifier);

}

})
```

The main idea is here

```
.directive('sampleDirective', function(sampleService) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        sampleService.registerTagCallback("tagsHover",tagCallback);

        function tagCallback(tag) {
            scope.tag = tag;
        }

    },
    template: "<div>{{tag.message}}</div>"
}

})
```

This directive (when it's registered and it's link function is activated) will use that service to register a callback that should execute inside your factory when you set a tag from inside of that factory. That could be done like so

```
.service('sampleService', function() {


return {
    setTag: setTag,
    registerTagCallback, registerTagCallback
}

var callbacks;
var tags;

function setTag(tag, identifier) {
    if (!tags || tags.length == 0)
        tags = [];

    tags.push({
        tag: tag,
        identifier: identifier
    });


    angular.forEach(callbacks, function(callback) {

       if (callback.identifier == identifier) {
          callback.method(tag);
       }

    });


}


function registerTagCallback(identifier, callback) {

    if (!callbacks || callbacks.length == 0)
        callbacks = [];

    callbacks.push({
        identifier: identifier,
        method: callback
    });

}

})
```

Everytime you set a tag, you check your registered callbacks to see if anyone is interested in receiving the tag, and invoke that callback with the tag that was passed in. The directive then updates it's scope internally from the registered callback functions param.

Here's a fiddle I put together with a working example. the tag identifier needs to match the directives callback identifier (which is "tagsHover" in this case), then you should see the directive update with the name and message of the tag

https://jsfiddle.net/5c88pte6/4/

Comment: Thanks! That super clean, implementing this now... will be back

Comment: Hmm having trouble at the moment with my code connecting to the Directive (not a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/wjg83rL7/) `registerTagCallback` does get called 4 times in my Service... looks like the Directive is calling the callback right away, before the user has a chance to roll over any tags

Comment: Ok I'll check this answer for now, I'll have to remake another question with my own plnkr and link to it here, thanks!